# C++ Using a while loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a c++ program to read a line of inputed code (eg The Hat is flat) and get the program to output the number of capital letters the code has. (in this example it would have to output 2). I have written a piece of code using `cin.get()` but my code is not entering the while loop. Please help me. and please change 'my code' only.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main () 
{
    char y = 0; 
    int capitals = 0; 
    int flag = 0;

    cout << "Enter your line of words followed by a fullstop: "; 

    while (!flag == -1)
    {
        cin.get(y);
        if ((y >= 65) && (y <= 90))
        {
             capitals = capitals + 1; 
        }         

        if (y == 46)
        {        
            flag = -1; 
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of capitals equal is this line is: " << capitals << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: yikes!  Make sure you indent your code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flag` is initialised to 0, `!flag` is therefore 1, and your while loop is never entered.

You could fix this with:

```
while (!(flag == -1))
```

or

```
while (flag != -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `!flag == -1` use `flag != -1`.

`!` is a unary logical NOT operator, and `!0` is 1, not -1.

Comment: Or better yet, get rid of `flag` and use `y != '.'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
while (!(flag == -1))
```

or

```
while (flag != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `while (!(flag == -1))` ... but it would be better to write `while (flag != -1)`.  The `!` operator has higher precedence so it is evaluated before `==`.
Also you should try to use `isupper()` to test for uppercase -- don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is operator precedence.  `!flag == -1` is equivalent to `(!flag) == -1`.  Try `flag != -1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll forgive a probably-too-complete answer to a probable homework question:

```
while (cin >> y && y != '.')
    capitals += (bool)isupper(y);
```