# C++ cin.get before a loop

Tags: c++

hey guys, i'm designing a C++ program that reads a sequence of one or more positive real numbers terminated by a negative number. To test that this has been done correctly i'm outputting the 5th number entered by the user. i am using a while loop to populate my array HOWEVER, my `cin.get(x)` is making my program not compile. please help my fix my code.

P.S this is the compliers error(s) if it is any help:

> solution1.cpp: In function `‘int main()’`:
>   
> solution1.cpp:19: error: no matching function for call to `‘std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::get(int&)’`
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:280:
>   
> note: candidates are: `typename std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::int_type std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::get() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]`
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:294:
>   
> note: `std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::get(_CharT&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]`
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:321:
>   
> note: `std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::get(_CharT*, std::streamsize, _CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]`
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:332:
>   
> note: `std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::get(_CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]`
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:355:
>   
> note: `std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::get(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]`
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:365:
>   
> note: `std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::get(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]`

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{
    char num[100] = {0};
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    cout << "Please enter line of numbers: ";

    while (flag > 0)
    {
        cin.get(x);

        if (x < 0)
        {
            flag = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            num[y] = x;
            y = y + 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "           " << num[4] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "yikes! Make sure you indent your code!", as someone said on [another of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5864112/78845).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really trying to read character-by-character, change `cin.get(x)` to `x = cin.get()`, but from the context I'm guessing you want to read a whole number. For that, use `cin >> x`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to read an integer from the command line, then the syntax is `cin >> x;`. `cin.get()` reads a single character, and returns it by value.

Comment: thankyou my program complies. however though lol my program doesnt work haha must just be poorly writen by me. can u guess why the program does nothing when i change this?

Comment: You start with "flag=0". Then your while loop says "while(flag>0)". Since 0 is not greater than 0, the while loop is completely skipped and your program does nothing.

Comment: @Brandon: because you intialise `flag` to zero, so the program never enters the `while (flag > 0)` block. It might be clearer to make it a boolean, with a name (like `done`) to indicate its purpose. Then use it as `bool done = false;`, `while (!done)`, and `done = true;`. Or drop it completely, and use `break` to exit the loop when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Use "x= cin.get();" instead of "cin.get(x);"

For more information see all variations of cin.get at below mentioned link,

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/